# How to define keyboard shortcut for a URL in Firefox on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a Firefox add-on or trick to define keyboard shortcuts to URLs?

For example, assigning a hotkey (in Firefox or Ubuntu) to quickly access a site. I'm using [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) Linux.

Comment: Is FireFox your default browser? IF so you can create a shortcut in i.e. Document folder and check for the properties and then assign a specific key combination that you want. Or you could try 
`firefox.exe "www.mozilla.org" "www.mozillazine.org"`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I'm using Ubuntu Linux. Can not bear windows a sec!

Comment: I wish you had mentioned that earlier.

Comment: I believe you can still use [FireFox command line args](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Command_line_arguments)

Comment: @Darius It is possible in Linux too, but a bit too verbose to type in terminal something like 'firefox google.com/?someStringhere'. I hope to be able to map this to a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: @Synetech I edited the question and added the OS.

Comment: Apparently someone decided to rewrite AutoHotKey as [IronAHK](http://www.ironahk.net/) which is cross platform

Comment: @wbad, you dont need to type it in terminal everytime, like in windows you can create a launcher which calls firefox with the website url

Comment: @KarthikT I know creating a launcher is one way to that, but I already have shortage of space on the panel so looking for alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SiteLauncher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sitelauncher/) might be what you are looking for.
According to [this site](http://www.labnol.org/software/website-keyboard-shortcuts/9354/).

```
if you need something more simple (and beautiful), check out Site Launcher.
You hit a shortcut key and there you have a list of all your favorite pages presented 
in a clean overlay window – press another key and the associated website will open 
in a new Firefox tab.
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's just one URL, you can set it as your homepage. Then press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> simultaneously to take you home (you may need to press it twice).

Otherwise, check out [SiteLauncher](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10127). Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to launch, and you should be well on your way.

SiteLauncher also has [an official website](http://www.donesmart.com/sitelauncher/).

Comment: Well, I wish I could set a correspondence between a couple of shortcut keys and some urls. Not only setting the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

This works at least for Ubuntu 12.04 / Firefox 22.0:

Go to keyboard -> shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts -> "+" (to create a new one), you can define the command like "firefox http://www.yoururl.com".

Once defined, you can set the actual shortcut as usual.

This will work as long as the Firefox command takes an URL for a parameter.